# Browsing Sharepoint site for the first time generates 404 Error

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-404

In our team we have a Sharepoint site where news, guidelines and files in general are posted.

But the weird thing is, when browsing it for the first time, we get a 404-Not Found Error. All the subsequent attempts to access it are sucessful.

This isn't a major problem at all, but I wonder, are there known causes for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for ServerFault, but my first guess is that you have IIS configured in such a way that your request is timing out and returning a 404 before Sharepoint has finished its first-run compilation on the homepage.

Comment: That sounds possible... but if timeout were the problem, wouldn't IIS be returning a timeout-related message (e.g. 408)?

Comment: That would seem like the obvious thing to do, but then Sharepoint very rarely does what one would expect. It is a classic exemplar of the Principle Of Most Surprise in almost every aspect of design and architecture.